# How do I add the rules to the htaccess file correctly and change the urls I need?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I wanted to change some url addresses on my wordpress site, without renaming folders. How do I add the rules to the htaccess file correctly and change the urls I need? All my attempt to do this were unsuccessful... Please help me solve my problem. I have an example of my broken code below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mytheme/(.+) /wp-content/themes/storefront/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^kyc/(.+) "/wp-content/plugins/my-reg-form/$1" [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^apps/(.+) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^includes/(.+) /wp-includes/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^media/(.+) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^review.php /wp-comments-post.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^content/(.+) /wp-content/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can't do it this way. WordPress uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and the value of that doesn't change by doing internal rewrites in the .htaccess, it keeps the originally requested URL.

Comment: CBroe, how can I do that? Can you tell me some working method?

Comment: For static assets the above might work, but anything "dynamic" you'll probably need to do using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

Comment: CBroe, add_rewrite_rule adds entries to the htaccess file? I'm almost a beginner, I don't think I can do it. Maybe you know some resources where I could figure out in detail how to change links without renaming folders in wordpress...

Comment: No, `add_rewrite_rule` does not add anything to the .htaccess, it adds routing rules that WP will evaluate internally. Do't know any guide that explains specifically what you want off the top of my head now though, you'll have to do some research.

Comment: I suppose you will have to implement a bit of both here. `RewriteRule ^media/(.+) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L,QSA]` - in the uploads folder, you are accessing actually existing files - so this part can still be done in .htaccess, and probably also rather _should_ be done there. (Because if you let those requests proceed into the actual WP routing process, then you will have to deliver the files _via code_ as well.)

Comment: Cbre, thank you for your time, I will look for useful information, maybe I will find something....

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have a folder there.

!Please take a thorough backup of files and database before you try anything!

1. It's `pattern` `replacement` and not the other way around

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(.*)$ media$1 [L,R=301]`

The flags mean that `L` is last to be processed and `R` for Redirect.

2. Please add it inside .htaccess but after the WordPress specific stuff and not in the same block as you show in the code. (Also mind that if you trigger the reproduction of permalinks this code might change)

Therefore the `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/anything`
will become `http://example.com/media/anything`

There is an excellent website that you can test all that:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=d1f361ae-27f1-4bef-afd0-7fae6c1c7be5

3. Furthermore you need to add `define( 'UPLOADS', 'media' );` into your `wp-config.php` file.
4. Move your files to that location.
5. Ensure that access in that location is allowed!

Once you visit your media library the URL for each media file should be pointing in the new URL structure.

I tested it on the https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ and then on my live apache2 website. That's why I am using answer instead of comments.